# Java converting pixel to dp

Tags: java

I have a `pixel` input and i want to convert it to `DP` using **Java**.

what **formula** should i use? or there is an **external library** than i can use!?

This code is common in android sdk. Is there a way to use it outside of Android?

```
public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px){
        DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
        float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
        return Math.round(dp);
    }
```

**Iam not using it for android i use it in a java application so i want to know how to do it in java not android.**

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Iam not using it for android i use it in a java application so i want to know how to do it in java not android

Comment: You should edit your question and make this clear then.  I don't see any reason why the duplicate questions would not cover your use case though.

Comment: IntelliJ is just an editor. What actual environment are you trying to write code for?

Comment: @bmargulies java application

Comment: @Hatem what exactly are you using it for in your application? Is this for an image or for a screen?

Comment: @vshcherbinin i have an input file that have some pixel values and i want to convert them to dp values and add this values into a file all just i need is the conversion formula or method

Comment: @Hatem well, the formula for pixel-to-dp is  dp = px / (dpi / 160). You can just use that straight away, if you know what your dpi value is. The dpi value is a smartphone related concept, so I dont know why you want to do a desktop application out of it.

Comment: @vshcherbinin my application generates xml files that can be used for android development :)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#dips-pels